# how to get number locate at 2 place before decimal point?

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, decimal-point

example: i have a number=143.42 , i want to get "4" which is locate 2 place before decimal point. what SQL command should i use? 
i still new in SQL, don't roast me too hard.

Comment: You need to be specific and forth coming with info. Please give any code that you have used to ask question otherwise we do not know your thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with some simple math

`SELECT 143.42 div 10 % 10;`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/144241)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to *floor* the column value using `FLOOR()` function to get rid of the decimal values -

```
select FLOOR(number) from table; -- this will give you 143
```

Then divide it with `10` to to get first two digit-

```
select FLOOR(number/10) from table; -- this will give you 14
```

After that if you divisible it with `10` using `MOD()` function you will get your answer -

```
select FLOOR(MOD(number/10, 10)) from table; -- this will give you 4
```

[Look at this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/977630/3) to see how it works.